# Как убрать дубляжи из вектора целых чисел?

Tags: stl, алгоритм, c++

На ум приходит:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){
std::vector<int> iv;

iv.push_back(2);
iv.push_back(3);
iv.push_back(3);
iv.push_back(3);
iv.push_back(45);
iv.push_back(1);
iv.push_back(1);
iv.push_back(3);

std::sort(iv.begin(), iv.end());
iv.erase(unique(iv.begin(), iv.end()));

return 0;
}
```

Но не работает почему-то.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы забыли указать второй итератор для [`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase):

```
iv.erase(unique(iv.begin(), iv.end()), iv.end());
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/JHeMWO.

Comment: Большое спасибо, хороший человек, просто у меня в редакторе автоподстановки нет. По памяти все пишу.

Answer (score 2):

Как уже сказал [@VladD](/users/10105/vladd), Вы не указали второй параметр для `erase`.

Вот что происходит в Вашем случае:
`unique(iv.begin(), iv.end())` возвращает итератор на элемент, следующий за последним не удаленным. В классе `vector` определено два метода `erase` с разным списком параметров. Вы воспользовались тем, который удаляет элемент, на который указывает переданный итератор. Если бы Вы посмотрели вывод того, что у Вас происходит, то увидели бы примерно следующее:

```
Original vector:
2 3 3 3 45 1 1 3 
Sorted vector:
1 1 2 3 3 3 3 45 
Unique vector:
1 2 3 45 3 3 45
```

Легко заметить, что в последней строке элементов не 8, как было в исходном векторе, а 7, здесь не хватает одной тройки. И тут в Вашу голову должны были закрасться сомнения.

**Вывод номер раз:** нужно внимательно читать документацию.

**Вывод номер два:** логирование весьма полезная штука.